# Selenium - Unknown error - element input

Tags: selenium-webdriver, eclipse, autoit

I have make 3 function for `blank data`,`invaliddata` and `validdata`.

I have user autoit for the upload the the file from the window.

At the debug time script is run properly but at the run time it displays the below error.

**Code:**

```java
    [![package abc;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    
    public class Profile {
    
        Setup s1=new Setup();
        Login l1=new Login();
        
        @BeforeTest
        public void setup()
        {
            s1.openbroweser();
            
        }
        @Test(priority=1)
        public void profile()
        {
            s1.getdriver().get("google.com");
            WebElement email=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("email"));
            email.clear();
            email.sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
            
            WebElement password=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("password"));
            password.clear();
            password.sendKeys("heena1");
            
            WebElement signin=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.id("m_login_signin_submit"));
            signin.click();
        }
        
        @Test(priority=2)
        public void blankdata() throws InterruptedException, IOException
        {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            WebElement pic=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.className("form-control"));
            pic.click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Rutvi \\Desktop\\fileupload.exe");
            
            WebElement name=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("name"));
            name.clear();
            name.sendKeys(" ");
            
            WebElement phno=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("phone")); 
            phno.clear();
            phno.sendKeys(" ");
            
            WebElement comname=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("company_name"));
            comname.clear();
            comname.sendKeys(" ");
            
            WebElement vatno=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("vat_number"));
            vatno.clear();
            vatno.sendKeys(" ");
            
            WebElement cocno=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("coc_number"));
            cocno.clear();
            cocno.sendKeys(" ");
            
            WebElement address=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("address"));
            address.clear();
            address.sendKeys(" ");
            
            WebElement postalcode=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("postal_code"));
            postalcode.clear();
            postalcode.sendKeys(" ");
            
            WebElement provience=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("provincie"));
            Select dropdown= new Select(provience);
        //  dropdown.selectByIndex(3);
            
            WebElement save=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.id("update_user_profile"));
            save.click();       
        }
        
        @Test(priority=3)
        public void invaliddata() throws InterruptedException, IOException
        {
            
            WebElement pic=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.className("form-control"));
            pic.click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Rutvi\\Desktop\\wrongfileupload.exe");
            
            WebElement name=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("name"));
            name.clear();
            name.sendKeys("Rutvi");
            
            WebElement phno=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("phone"));
            phno.clear();
            phno.sendKeys("9012345678");
            
            WebElement comname=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("company_name"));
            comname.clear();
            comname.sendKeys("search native");
            
            WebElement vatno=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("vat_number"));
            vatno.clear();
            vatno.sendKeys("123454");
            
            WebElement cocno=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("coc_number"));
            cocno.clear();
            cocno.sendKeys("89798");
            
            WebElement address=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("address"));
            address.clear();
            address.sendKeys("ahmedabad");
            
            WebElement postalcode=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("postal_code"));
            postalcode.clear();
            postalcode.sendKeys("1234AS");
            
            WebElement provience=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("provincie"));
            Select dropdown= new Select(provience);
            dropdown.selectByIndex(3);
            
            WebElement save=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.id("update_user_profile"));
            save.click();
        
        }
        
        @Test(priority=4)
        public void validdata() throws InterruptedException, IOException
        {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            WebElement pic=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.className("form-control"));
            pic.click();
            
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Rutvi\\Desktop\\fileupload.exe");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            WebElement name=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("name"));
            name.clear();
            name.sendKeys("Rutvi");
            
            WebElement phno=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("phone"));
            phno.clear();
            phno.sendKeys("9012345678");
            
            WebElement comname=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("company_name"));
            comname.clear();
            comname.sendKeys("search native");
            
            WebElement vatno=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("vat_number"));
            vatno.clear();
            vatno.sendKeys("123454");
            
            WebElement cocno=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("coc_number"));
            cocno.clear();
            cocno.sendKeys("89798");
            
            WebElement address=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("address"));
            address.clear();
            address.sendKeys("ahmedabad");
            
            WebElement postalcode=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("postal_code"));
            postalcode.clear();
            postalcode.sendKeys("1234AS");
            
            WebElement provience=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.name("provincie"));
            Select dropdown= new Select(provience);
            dropdown.selectByIndex(3);
            
            WebElement save=s1.getdriver().findElement(By.id("update_user_profile"));
            save.click();
        
        }
        
    }
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Can you show us the error in text? Not in screen shot.

Comment: @AlexeyR.org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <input type="file" class="form-control m-input" name="file" value="1534229067.jpg"> is not clickable

Comment: Other tests have Thread.sleep as the first line while the failed one doesn't/ Try add sleep period before the tests starts.

Comment: i have try with that but display same error

Comment: It probably is not your reported error, but the line `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Rutvi \\Desktop\\fileupload.exe");` contains an extra space after your name.  Which line, exactly, is reporting the error?  There's a LOT of lines in your sample code.